# Why the output of java program while using ^ operator is this?

Tags: java, operators, powerset

I have made a program in which i want to calculate the power set size.But i am unable to do it because the ouput of the statement 1 is 0?Why is this showing wrong?

```
public class PowerSetDemo 
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {

     int q=0;
     char a[]={'a','b'};
     int p=a.length;
     System.out.println(p);

     q=2^p;        //error here
     System.out.println(q);    Why 0?

    }
}
```

OutputShown
2
0

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.pow` not `^`.
`^` is a bitwise operation, as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Refer to [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) for more information.

Comment: I want to calculate the length of this set by using my own logic first.Then i will use those predefined functions to make my life easy.Is there any other way i can calculate the length of the no of combinations?

Answer (score 1):

`p` is the length of the array which is  2.

When you [xor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) 2 with 2 (or any other number with itself) you get zero:

```
2^2 = 0
```

Comment: Okay in java its xor.While using calculator i thought may be i can calculate the length of the no combination of powers.Is there any other way i can calculate the length of the no of combinations?

Comment: @mansikbchawla as Gosu suggested - use `Math.pow` to calculate power. As for combinations - I'm not familiar with a library that does it for you, but you can easily [google it](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Combinations.java)